# How to open phpmyadmin as domain in localhost?

Tags: docker, nginx

I have one docker-compose file that have nginx, mysql and phpmyadmin. 
phpmyadmin is open in port `8080` in this address `mydomain.com:8080` as well.

How can I convert this address to `http://phpmyadmin.mydomain.com` or `http://pma.mydomain.com` in my server?

I have used this docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./Beh:/var/www
      - ./Config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
#       - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./Beh:/var/www
      - ./Config/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  database:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: database
    environment:
        - "MYSQL_USERNAME=root"
        - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - app-network


  phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      environment:
          - "MYSQL_USERNAME=root"
          - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
          - "PMA_HOST=database"
      links:
          - database
      ports:
          - "8080:80"
      networks:
      - app-network



#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

I don't know how to configure nginx file to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the repo -> https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy
This is what I'm using to create new local domain name for each project.
You have to add "VIRTUAL_HOST" to the environment, expose the ports ("expose: 80") and also add the new domain in your /etc/hosts.